# Cannot create local repository

Tags: github-for-windows

I have a folder of scripts (E:\ScheduledTasks) that I'd like to put under source control. I installed github for windows but did not link it to my github account, as I do not wish any kind of integration with github, only the nice UI features of it for a local repository.

When I drag the folder to the UI, the "Create" pop-up appears, but when I click "Create repository" I get "Failed to create repository. An error occurred while creating the repository. You might need to open a shell and debug the state of this repo." (What repo? It doesn't even exist yet)

When I click on "Create", browse to the folder and enter the name of the repository, a subfolder with the same name gets created (E:\ScheduledTasks\ScheduledTasks) and an empty repository is created.

When I click on "Create", set the local path to E: and the name to ScheduledTasks, I get the same error as above.

When I use the Git shell to git init a repo in E:ScheduledTasks, I get the proper E:\ScheduledTasks.git. I can then add some files.

If I then try to drag E:\ScheduledTasks to GitHub for Windows, I get taken to the "Create" popup and get an error message saying "Repository with the same name already exists at this location". (Of course it does, I'm trying to add it, not create it....)

If I click on "Add" and browse to E:\ScheduledTasks, I get the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but little advice is to try https://tortoisegit.org/, you may get better windows experience with it then original git for windows UI.